# Building a static mobile web app with Backbone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, backbone.js, web-applications

I am still researching about the right frameworks to use for an upcoming project. I need to develop a static web app that will be running on iPad, iPhone, Galaxy Tab 10.1 and Android devices with a resolution of 480x800px. This web app will be static, no interaction with a server.

Since I like Backbone very much, I was asking myself if it would be useful using it for something static. The advantages I see are especially in structuring code in general, separating different views and making use of the events in the views. Would you recommend using Backbone for this - what are the advantages and disadvantages you see in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

From your question i am getting that you want to make an app that could be run on both iOS and android devices.

A few weeks earlier i was also looking for the same question and after looking at couple of mobile frameworks available in markets like (rhoMobile,Appcelerator,and phonegap) I choose Appcelerator.

Its a great framework. If you are comfortable with ruby then you can opt for rhoMobile too.

This framework can easily work with webServices etc written in php and other.

Like backbone, Titanium Appcelerator also uses javascript and provide rich API for your application development.

Comment: Hi Ajeet, thanks for your quick reply. I am not looking for a hybrid solution like you suggested. It will be completely browser-based using HTML/CSS/Javascript. Of course, something like Phonegap could be used to get native Apps out of it, but at the moment that is not what I am looking for.